# Determining the movieclip assigned to a variable in an array AS3

Tags: arrays, for-loop, actionscript-3

Please forgive my terminology, Im not educated on the proper.

Lets say I have multiple movieclip variables

```
var rblock1:MovieClip = new Rblock();
var rblock2:MovieClip = new Rblock();
var rblock3:MovieClip = new Rblock();
var yblock1:MovieClip = new Yblock();
var yblock2:MovieClip = new Yblock();
var yblock3:MovieClip = new Yblock();
```

I have them added to an array

```
var blockarray:Array = new Array(rblock1, rblock2, rblock3, yblock1, yblock2, yblock3);
var block
```

I want to create a for loop with an if statement that triggers if a variable is Rblock and not Yblock, for example

```
for each (block in blockarray)
{ 

    if (block==Rblock)
    { 
         trace("rblock");
    }

}
```

The issue is that obviously "if (block==Rblock)" doesnt work.
How should this be written?

Comment: Case sensitivity.

Comment: no im not trying to declare the clip, im trying to declare the class, the class is Rblock, the clip is rblock

Comment: i have edited the question to avoid the confusion that you were right to assume

Comment: To check if an instance belongs to a class you use **if (block is Rblock)** statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apparently want to check if a block is red or yellow by checking against its *class name*. You can do it with this:

```
if (block is Rblock) {...} // yes, red
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a work around not really a perfect solution, which will only work for certain scenarios...

if each class has a unique trait you can identify it that way, for example...

if all variables defined by the Rblock class are wider than the Yblock class you could say

```
if (block.width>x) { trace(Rblock); }
```

Like I said this is only a work around though and only works for movieclip variables defined by classes that are different, if anyone has the actual solution please post

Comment: There are traits, namely class names, or also a common name of a superclass, you can perform checks against class name with `if (block is Rblock)` (in fact you check if this block is *either* `Rblock` or a descendant of `Rblock` this way, but normally you only check against a leaf class, so this is irrelevant).